# Duplicate property mapping of bitmap$init$0 found when using @MappedSuperclass in a Scala Play 2.0.4 app with Hibernate 3.6.10 JPA

Tags: hibernate, scala, jpa, playframework-2.0

Has anyone seen this exception before and knows how to resolve the issue?

We are having a Scala Play 2.0.4 project and Hibernate 3.6.10 as the JPA backend.

The entity in question is extending a class annotated with @MappedSuperclass i.e.

```
@Entity
class EntityWithError(id: UUID,_name:String) extends Parent(id){

    @Column(name="name") var name = _name
}

@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Parent(_id: UUID) {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "id") val id: String = _id.toString()
}
```

This throws a org.hibernate.MappingException with "Duplicate property mapping of bitmap$init$0 found".

Any ideas?

I've created a minimal Play 2.0.4 project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/tinoadams/play_jpa_mappedsuperclass

Cheers
Tino